# Paypal integration with asp.net

Tags: paypal, integration

I have created paypal account on paypal site for testing(buyer and seller account). I developed a site and created a page that redirects me on paypal site to buy the product. Now login is required there for buyer. Can i login there for my test account? that is mypaypalid@live.com, (as i given my @live id and they returned me paypal with @live.com)
help me plz as soon as posible...

Comment: arent you supposed to use the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set tests accounts through https://developer.paypal.com/ (signup required, separate from your Live PayPal account).

In here, create one buyer/seller account. Change the "action" for your   to point to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr, as opposed to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
Don't forget to modify 'business' of your button to match the Sandbox seller account you just created.